# Video unavailable youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am using Youtube's API to load in a video. The video I had previously I had no issues loading this but I changed the url to a new video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjZGWRAoGO4" however the video dose not play, it just says video unavailable. Which settings in Youtube would the owner need to change to allow me to use this video as embedded? Or any Javascript I can use that can override this?

Comment: No, the owner of the content controls that...

Comment: What settings would the owner need to change? @SakoBu

Answer (score 0):

Need to go to youtube settings > video manager > click edit on video > advanced settings > distrbution options > selected allow embedding.

Comment: Please remember **[accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**.

Comment: Didn't work when embeding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EzdmE4Ewqk